# Deep versus flat module hierarchies in Python

Tags: python

Some libraries in Python are organized as a hierarchy of submodules. What are the pros and cons of such an design from the of view of the user of the library?

For instance:

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import dijkstra
```

versus:

```
from scipy.csgraph import dijkstra
```

or even an entirely flat design:

```
from scipy import dijkstra
```

*Note*:

1. This question is specifically about Python, because idiomatic Python
   makes other tradeoffs than say idiomatic Java.
2. I am talking about the user interface, not how you should structure your code as a library designer.

Comment: Nice question, but i think this is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Maybe, but I think there are at least some objective pro and cons to either approach such as module loading time, amount of typing, compatibility with existing tools (autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

I think the *objective* aspects specific to *interfaces* in *Python* packages will contain at least the following:

- Name spacing
  In case you have several `dijkstra` implementations in your package, it obviously makes sense to put them in different submodules to avoid strange names like `miller_dijkstra` or `dijkstra_v1`.  By putting each implementation in a separate module, this can never clash.
- Forward declaration
  In some cases you can get problems in Python if you have cyclic imports.  Then putting everything in a separate module can sometimes help solve these issues.